# Why was the "not a real question" flag declined?

Tags: support, flags, not-a-real-question

I flagged the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603634/how-do-i-round-down-a-randomly-generated-number-in-python-e-g-random-randrange as not a real question.

My flag was declined and then the question was closed as too localized.

I agree with the "too localized", but since the body is

> School assignment to basically make a game, for the attributes section we need to be able to roll a dice and the number should round itself down. Thanks for the help in advance.:p

how could it be a real question?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Someone had also thrown a "spam or offensive" flag on that post, so the moderator probably declined that from the moderator dashboard without noticing that there was another flag on the post.  When we take action on one flag, it dismisses all active flags on the same post for whichever reason we select.  You're right though, that's 100% "not a real question".  Sorry about the declined flag.

Comment: Super clear! Thank you very much.

Comment: @888 You're welcome.  "Spam or offensive" flags are fairly rare compared to other types, so you just got unlucky. Please keep flagging the way you have been.